# Writing a txt file while running some calculations

Tags: c, windows, loops, collatz

I am trying to create a program that outputs in a txt file the results of [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture). However when I try to do it with big numbers, like 1,000,000, it does not work properly and always stops at 113383.

Here is the code:

```
int n, count, number, mayor, masvueltas, top;
char c = '@';
freopen("output MILLION.txt", "w", stdout);
count = 0;
number = 1;
mayor = 0;
masvueltas = 0;
while(number != 1000000) {
    printf("\n%d did ", number);//this will say that number did COUNT loops
    n = number;
    while (n != 1) {
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            n = n / 2;
            count++;
        }
        else {
            n = 3 * n + 1;
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf(" %d saltos.\n", count);//Here continoues the sentence
    char graf[count];//creates an array to print the @ character COUNT times
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        graf[i] = c;
        printf("%c", graf[i]);
    }
    if(masvueltas < count) {
        masvueltas = count;
        mayor = number;
    }
    number++;
    count = 0;
}
```

Also if you know how to print the ASCII character 219, block, in a txt file it would be great. Is not important just so I have a cleaner txt file.

Comment: What's the purpose of `graf`? You don't need an array to print `count` at signs, just `putchar('@')` or `printf("@")` it in a loop.

Comment: Have you tried using a larger data type for the candidate, such as `long long int`? Starting with around 1,000,000 it doesn't have to take the path `n=(3*n)+1;` very many times in succession to break the storage range.

Comment: Oh, yes. you are right @WeatherVane. With long long int works. Is there  a way to modify how big can it be or is it limited by default?

Comment: ... and indeed `1001063` does break the `int` limit after 149 iterations.

Comment: Well, you can test if it will break the data type before you do `n * 3 + 1` by comparing with the maximum value that is safe. For example, with `int` the maximum safe value is `(INT_MAX - 1) / 3`.

Answer (score 0):

This happened because for `number` = 113,383 the calculations reach the value of 827,370,449 after 119 counts, the next count max the value 2,482,111,348 which is more than the [maximum value of int variable 2,147,483,647](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?view=vs-2019), which makes the value of `n` becomes negative, -1812855948, and the loop fails to reach 1. You should use `long long n` instead to get the results you want. I also recommend that you use `for` loop instead of `while` loop.